# Repeating Column Value Into Row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, rows

I'm wondering how to turn a column which contains repetitive column values into rows in MSSQL. Here is an example of what I'm working with.

```
CREATE TABLE Colors
(
    Time_ Time,
    Color varchar(6),
    count int
)

INSERT INTO Colors VALUES ('10:00', 'Red', 2);
INSERT INTO Colors VALUES ('10:00', 'Orange', 3);
INSERT INTO Colors VALUES ('10:00', 'Yellow', 6);
INSERT INTO Colors VALUES ('10:00', 'Green', 9);
INSERT INTO Colors VALUES ('10:00', 'Blue', 2);
INSERT INTO Colors VALUES ('11:00', 'Red', 3);
INSERT INTO Colors VALUES ('11:00', 'Orange', 4);
INSERT INTO Colors VALUES ('11:00', 'Yellow', 6);
INSERT INTO Colors VALUES ('11:00', 'Green', 7);
INSERT INTO Colors VALUES ('11:00', 'Blue', 1);
INSERT INTO Colors VALUES ('12:00', 'Red', 2);
INSERT INTO Colors VALUES ('12:00', 'Orange', 2);
INSERT INTO Colors VALUES ('12:00', 'Yellow', 7);
INSERT INTO Colors VALUES ('12:00', 'Green', 9);
INSERT INTO Colors VALUES ('12:00', 'Blue', 4);
```

And SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/48657/1

What I'm looking for is a table where the rows are Time_, Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue. So it would look something like this:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  Time_,
        Red, 
        Orange, 
        Yellow, 
        Green, 
        Blue
FROM
    (
        SELECT  Time_, Color, Count
        FROM    Colors
    ) orgData
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(Count)
        FOR Color IN (Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue)
    ) pvt
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/48657/2)